# How to search for multiple tags on Behance

Tags: behance

I don't get it, how do you search with multiple tags on Behance?

For example say I want to search for "menu" as in interactive menu. The first result returns menus for restaurants so I enter the search term "interactive" in the search field and it replaces my first term "menu" with "interactive". Now I'm searching for something completely different.

I've tried separating search terms with commas and spaces and neither work. Because of this I've never been able to use Behance but I must be missing something. It can't be that limited surely or it's unusable as a searchable catalog and is just another design blog.

Enlighten me :)

Comment: You should contact Behance support. They'll be in the best position to answer questions about their product.

Comment: I agree that this question is borderline on off topic but Behance is widely used by designers and by asking here the answer will be widely available to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behance is indeed a bit cumbersome when it comes to search. You basically have to find the tagID of each tag (found by clicking on a tag and checking the URL) and combine them with a pipe in the URL.

Result: https://www.behance.net/search?user_tags=976875|971949

Pretty silly right? Let's hope someone can show us a better way...

Comment: Excellent answer, sorry for the delayed reply. I didn't receive any notifications there was a response.

Comment: No worries, glad to be able to help out. You probably didn't receive a notification because the mods closed the the topic.

Comment: In deed, it is better to 1) Search for a keyword 2) Click one of the search results and scroll until the section on which the tags are listed 3) Click the tag which matches the searched keyword 4) Search with keyword 2 on the tag listing page.